# Trying to use image as button (html, css, js), not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I am trying the make a page with a number of clickable images, when user clicks one of the images a popup (related to said image) should appear.

When i only add 1 image the code works and the popup is shown, but as soon as i add a second image (with different id), it doesn't work as intended anymore. when clicking the second image the code inside the eventlistener is executed (since "2nd button pressed" is logged to console) but strangely enough "popup2" is not shown...
When i click on 2nd button first and then on 1st button, popup2 is shown first and then when i click away popup 2, popup1 is shown..

What am i doing wrong? How can i make it such that when i click an image the correct popup window opens?

working code (1 button):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles */
    /* The modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;

    }

    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10% auto; /* 10% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div  class="imageTextGrid" name="overview">
            <a href="#2" id="image-link2"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>

        </div>

        <!-- popup -->
 
        <div id="popup2" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                Popup 2
            </div>    

        </body>

    <script>
        const imageLink2 = document.getElementById("image-link2");
        var popup2 = document.getElementById("popup2");

        // When the user clicks a button (or image), open relevant section

        imageLink2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log ("2nd button pressed");
        popup2.style.opacity = 1;
        popup2.style.display = "block";
        });

        popup2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target === popup2) {
            popup2.style.opacity = 0;
            popup2.style.display = "none";
        }
        });
        //end of button actions

    </script>
</html>
```

**code which doesnt work (added 2nd button(2nd clickable image which should open "popup2" but doesn't):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles */
    /* The modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;

    }

    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10% auto; /* 10% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div  class="imageTextGrid" name="overview">
            <a href="#" id="image-link"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            <a href="#2" id="image-link2"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>

        </div>

        <!-- popup -->
        
        <div id="popup" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                apeldoorn Popup
            </div>
        <div id="popup2" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                Popup 2
            </div>    

        </body>

    <script>

        // Get buttons (image text grids)
        const imageLink = document.getElementById("image-link");
        const imageLink2 = document.getElementById("image-link2");

        // var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        var popup2 = document.getElementById("popup2");

        // When the user clicks a button (or image), open relevant section
        
        imageLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log ("1st button pressed");
        popup.style.opacity = 1;
        popup.style.display = "block";
        });

        popup.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target === popup) {
            popup.style.opacity = 0;
            popup.style.display = "none";
        }
        });

        imageLink2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log ("2nd button pressed");
        popup2.style.opacity = 1;
        popup2.style.display = "block";
        });

        popup2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target === popup2) {
            popup2.style.opacity = 0;
            popup2.style.display = "none";
        }
        });
        //end of button actions

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close popup div tag

```
<div id="popup" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                apeldoorn Popup
            </div>
        <div id="popup2" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                Popup 2
            </div>
```

Should be

```
<div id="popup" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                apeldoorn Popup
            </div>
    </div>
        <div id="popup2" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                Popup 2
            </div>
</div>
```